# DateADD with codeigniter, to get the entry of the last 30 days

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

here's my method called in my model:

```
return $this->db->select('*')
->from($this->table)
->where('date >',DateADD(day, -30, Current_TimeStamp))
->get()
->result();
```

so then I have this error:

```
fatal error: Call to undefined function DateADD()
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not `DateADD` function.

Use like [DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) function.

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)
```

Comment: yes always the same I think there are something wrong with DateAdd